# Errors running commands in parallel with python multiprocessing

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, multiprocess

I am trying to parallelize several command line calls in python, using PyCharm IDE. However I am getting some odd errors which I do not understand.

```
from generate_command_list import create_list
import multiprocessing
import subprocess

x = create_command_list().values

def execute_commandline_call(executable):
    subprocess.call(executable, shell=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in x:
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=execute_commandline_call,args=(i,))
        p.start()
        #p.join() # not needed as each run is independent of each other
```

The `create_command_list` returns a dataframe of strings which I want executed from the terminal. The expected output is that I am able to run all of these commands in parallel. However the errors I am getting refer back to the `generate_command_list` function.

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   'excel_document.xlsx'

is an error returned which makes no sense to me. This excel document is used to create the list of executables but I do not see why it is part of the error here.

Comment: The error says file not found.  Find the file to continue.

Answer (score 0):

**x** may not pickle correctly or rely something not pickle correctly?

try:

```py
x = [str(cmd) for cmd in create_command_list().values]
```